Subtracting Decimal Variables in PHP and Comparing the Output
I am trying to work out why this simple code isn't giving the expected result;
$qty = 2;
$vol = 1.1;

//$vol1 equals 0.1
$vol1 = $vol - 1;

//$qty1 equals 1
$qty1 = $qty - 1;


//when $sum is echoed this equals 0.1
$sum = ($vol1 / $qty1);

//Below always echos No Micros.  $sum == 0.1 or $sum === 0.1 is never true
if ($sum === 0.1) {
    echo "Micros";
} else {
    echo "No Mircos";
}


If i manually set the variables $vol1 and $qty1 like this;
//$vol1 equals 0.1
$vol1 = 0.1;

//$qty1 equals 1
$qty1 = 1;


//when $sum is echoed equals 0.1
$sum = ($vol1 / $qty1);

//Below always echos No Micros.  $sum == 0.1 or $sum === 0.1 is never true
if ($sum === 0.1) {
    echo "Micros";
} else {
    echo "No Mircos";
}


The script evaluates true as expected.
I've tried floatval() on the numbers, but I don't believe I need to convert or cast them.  What am i missing when subtracting and the result is a decimal?
